# Html into search text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I return the elements of the list with a for loop.
I left one of the elements in this list below as an example.
My goal is to reach the label in this html and read the text value. How can I do that?

```
<li>
   <a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="3"> 
      <img class="dd-option-image" src="/Images/Sample/0.png"> 
      <label class="dd-option-text">Sampleee</label> 
      <small class="dd-option-description dd-desc">Sample sampleee.</small>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: It depends on the context, but in general you can do it like this: ``document.querySelector(".dd-option-text").value`` in plain JavaScript.

Comment: this code saw my work, thank you.

temp1.querySelector(".dd-option-text").textContent

Comment: Yes, ``textContent``. I wrote ``value`` without meaning to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using vanilla JS:**

You can find the element with [**`querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and access [**`innerText`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [**`textContent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

```js
var labelText = document.querySelector('label.dd-option-text').textContent;
console.log(labelText);
```

```html
<li>
   <a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="3"> 
      <img class="dd-option-image" src="/Images/Sample/0.png"> 
      <label class="dd-option-text">Sampleee</label> 
      <small class="dd-option-description dd-desc">Sample sampleee.</small>
   </a>
</li>
```

**Using jQuery:** Access the [**`text()`**](https://api.jquery.com/text/) on the returned object:

```js
var labelText = $('label.dd-option-text').text();
console.log(labelText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
   <a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="3"> 
      <img class="dd-option-image" src="/Images/Sample/0.png"> 
      <label class="dd-option-text">Sampleee</label> 
      <small class="dd-option-description dd-desc">Sample sampleee.</small>
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery**

```
let yourListElement = $("ul li")
console.log(yourListElement.find("label").text())
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
yourListElement.querySelector(".dd-option-text").textContent
```